# How do you determine if a user is already authenticated in Angular Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am writing a guard to re-direct users to the login page if they are unauthenticated using AngularFireAuth. Without this library, I would store a token in local/session storage and when the guard triggers, I would inspect the storage to see if a token exists. AngularFireAuth stores a token in the database (which contains authentication information):

[image: image of AngularFireAuth stored in Indexed DB in Firefox Dev Tools]

However it would be unwise to directly inspect this as AngularFireAuth could change how this works at any future date. It is not exactly part of the documented public API.

In older versions of AngularFireAuth, I could include this method in my service to do this check:

```js
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly service: AngularFireAuth) {}

  public login(credentials: Credentials) {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    return this.service.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return !!this.service.auth.currentUser;
  }
}
```

However this does not persist on refresh. So while I am navigating around the system, it works fine, but if I refresh or leave and come back, I am prompted to log in again.

How can I write my `isLoggedIn` method to be callable in my guard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using AngulaFireAuthGuard. Without adding any special method, it handles everything for you.

So, instead of using a regular guard, inside your app-routing.module you can directly add it.

This is an example:

into app.module:

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard'; 

@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [
      AngularFireAuthGuardModule,
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: []
})
```

and into app-routing.module:

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo, redirectLoggedInTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const redirectUnauthorizedToHome = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['home']);
const redirectLoggedInToAccount = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['my-account']);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'my-account', component: MyAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToHome } },
  { path: 'create-account', component: CreateAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToAccount } },
];
```

You can look at the details from here: 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md

Comment: I _just_ discovered this too, I read the Firebase Auth manual, but apparently I missed this in the AngularFire manual.

Comment: unfortunately, it's not well known. Maybe it's new I don't know. After struggling with my capstone project for days I suddenly found this and voila! Only downside is only documentation about that is the page I referred to. So, if you want to do something else, it's not clear. I am still looking for an answer for my own question about that :/

Comment: Some times, you must skip the manual and go straight to the source... code.

Comment: One gotcha I just worked past - the AngularFireAuthGuard has it's own module. 
`import { AngularFireAuthGuardModule } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';` this was unexpected.

Comment: oh yeah forgot to mention that, let me edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I needed to be able to determine if a user was logged in outside of my guard, so here is my solution:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly service: AngularFireAuth
  ) {}

  public login(credentials: Credentials): Promise<any> {
    const { email, password } = credentials;
    return this.service.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  public isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve: any) => {
      this.service.auth.onAuthStateChanged(( user: any ) => {
        user ? resolve(true) : resolve(false);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { AngularFireAuthGuard, redirectUnauthorizedTo, redirectLoggedInTo } from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const redirectUnauthorizedToHome = () => redirectUnauthorizedTo(['home']);
const redirectLoggedInToAccount = () => redirectLoggedInTo(['my-account']);

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'my-account', component: MyAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectUnauthorizedToHome } },
  { path: 'create-account', component: CreateAccountComponent, canActivate: [AngularFireAuthGuard], data: { authGuardPipe: redirectLoggedInToAccount } },
];
```

works for me, tks

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.